# No Input Signal

Tags: windows-7, display

I was playing a game 'Sniper Elite v2' on my system, when all of a sudden the computer froze up and started hearing a repeated noise (reloading the gun over and over again). I couldn't get any of the default escapes to work (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, Windows key). So I restarted the computer via the button. This time the computer didn't start up.

I just got the

> No Input Signal

displayed on my monitor and it switched to Analog mode.

Couple of hours later, I tried to switch it on and this time it started. I saw the initial screen (the black one that displays the system configurations) and then the next one (the one that displays the motherboard/chipset name or something.. it has a blueish color to it)  and then the prompt for accessing the bios came and the system froze up again.

Ever since then the system has only shown the "No Input Signal" on the monitor and then it switches to Analog mode.

My system configurations are:

- Win 7 Ultimate
- nVidia GeForce 8500 graphics card
- 2 GB RAM
- 160 GB hard disk (internal)
- An external 1 TB hard disk (powered)
- ViewSonic Monitor

Any other specs required?

So what maybe the problem? Faulty monitor cable or something? Loose connection? Or it is something more serious?

Comment: There was a blue tint? I'm inclined to think your video card is failing/has failed. Do you have a spare one you can swap in to test?

Comment: How is it first switching to digital and getting the no-signal error?  Does this happen spontaneously when you turn on the PC or are you manually switching it to digital?

Comment: @Bob No I don't have a spare one to test on :(

Comment: @Paul It shows the No Input Signal thing and then show Analog and then finally goes to sleep (green light of the monitor goes orange)

Comment: Does your computer have integrated graphics? If yes, try that.

Comment: @ShyamK That didn't answer my question.  What does the No Input appear in response to?  Turning on the PC or turning on the monitor, or manually switching the monitor to digital.  In other words, when you turn on the PC does the monitor spontaneously show the No Input error?

Comment: @Bob Oh okay.. My monitor is always on. So when I switch on the CPU the monitor indicator light turns from yellow (idle state) to green(active) then the display "No input signal" comes and then finally "Analog" is written and then the green light changes back to yellow.

Comment: @Bob Integrated graphics? whats that and how does that work?

Comment: See if you have a second (VGA, DVI, HDMI, DMS-59, etc.) port - one that's not on the video card. Integrated graphics are part of the motherboard/chipset/CPU, rather than being on a dedicated card. They will often have a port near the rear USB/Network/Audio/etc. ports, though not all motherboards have them. (@Paul I think he meant to ping you)

Comment: @Bob Yes I meant to ping him. Thanks for that. 
Okay I will check that and get back to either of you :) . But if memory serves right the computer didn't switch on when I had connected to the other port. (Had tried that out when I bought the damn thing)

Comment: @ShyamK You may have to take the nVidia card out first.

Comment: @ShyamK or a bios setting to tell it to prioritise the integrated over the nvidia.  As the monitor is responding to the PC turning on, the card has power, but doesn't then send a proper signal to display.  This is often due to the graphics card becoming loose.  Try re-seating it (open the case and jiggle the card into its slot).

Comment: @Bob Okay. But bad things happen when I open the pc cover..

Comment: @Paul Okay. I shall try kicking it back into its slot.

Comment: I shall get back to you both once that's done. :D

Comment: Seems that dusting my RAM has solved the issue here. Thanks Paul and Bob